# GTK3 theme dialog box renders solid black background in Audacity

Tags: css, gtk, gtk3, gnome

I was using Audacity with a GTK 3 theme I created. On some of the dialog boxes the background comes up as a solid black color, while the theme's background color is a light yellow. I noticed this happens only on some of the dialog boxes.

Below is an image of the Compressor dialog.

[image]

I want to know how to get the proper background color, as I checked some other themes with GTK Inspector and they render correctly.

The code for the gtk-widgets.css file is on this [GitHub page](https://github.com/jgpws/jgd-spring-awakening/blob/master/source-code/gtk-3.20/gtk-widgets.css).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try:

```
window > box > widget > widget { background-color:yellow; }
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick! It looks like widgets inside of widgets were not rendering correctly.

Thank you so much for solving this problem.